# php sort array like odd/even/odd/even

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Can I sort an array odd/even/odd/even ?is it possible via usort function? :

**first array**:

```
$array = ['a'=>'0','b'=>0,'c'=>0,'d'=1,'e'=>1,'f'=>1];
```

**second array**:

```
$result = ['d'=>1,'a'=>0,'e'=>1,'b'=>0,'f'=>1,'c'=>0];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be an equal number (or at least +-1) of 1s and 0s? If not, what's the desired behaviour in case they're unequal?

Comment: yse.The numbers are only zero and one.

Comment: but if you have 3 1's and 10 0's what do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: 3 1s & 10 0s : 1010100000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take..

```
// example array
$array = array('d'=>1,'a'=>0,'b'=>0,'c'=>0,'e'=>1,'f'=>1,'g'=>1,'h'=>1);

$temp=array();
$result=array();
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
  if ($v%2==0)
    $temp[0][$k]=$v;
  else
    $temp[1][$k]=$v;
}
$c = max(count($temp[0]),count($temp[1]));
for ($i=0;$i<$c;$i++) {
  $ok = key($temp[1]);
  if ($ok) {
    $result+=array($ok=>$temp[1][$ok]);
    next($temp[1]);
    $ok=false;
  }
  $ek = key($temp[0]);
  if ($ek) {
    $ek = key($temp[0]);
    $result+=array($ek=>$temp[0][$ek]);
    next($temp[0]);
    $ek=false;
  }
}

print_r($result);
// Array ( [d] => 1 [a] => 0 [e] => 1 [b] => 0 [f] => 1 [c] => 0 [g] => 1 [h] => 1 )
```